# Does this system have a limit cycle

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Does this system have a limit cycle? $$x' = y, y' = 2(1-xy)$$

I've tried transforming this into polar coordinates but it doesn't give nice equations so I didn't continue on with that.
Now I'm trying to do it using the Lyapunov function but I can't quite figure out $V(x, y)$ to make the whole thing work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a Lienard system that doesn't satisfy the conditions of Lienard's theorem for the existence of a limit cycle...

Comment: @A.Izmailov Oh okay, thank you!

Comment: Also note that any closed trajectory must enclose a domain that has at least one equilibrium point in the inside. If the equations in the OP are written correctly, this is the fastest way to figure out the answer.